# Why are these negative-lookaheads failing to constrain a regex pattern that decides when to perform substitutions with the re.sub() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

```py
import re

#Example input:
input_text = "en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las 2023_-_02_-_04 19:00 pm aasassa  2023_-_02_-_04 sdshdhshj 19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 fgfg"

date_format_00 = r"(\d*)_-_(\d{2})_-_(\d{2})"  # Y*_-_MM_DD
identificate_hours = r"(?:(\d{1,2})|)(?:(?:\:| )(\d{1,2})|)\s*(?:(am)|(pm)|)"

#I use a negative lookahead "(?!\()" to avoid matches
date_format_00_blocking = r"(?!\d*_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}\s*)"
identificate_hours_blocking = r"(?!\d{1,2}(?:\:| )\d{1,2}\s*(?:am|pm|))"


#Both re.sub() should achieve replacements of the type:  "2023_-_02_-_04"  --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(00:00 am))"
#However, only the first of the re.sub() (in the order of the reading of the code that the interpreter does) will do it, since after that it will already be labeled with the parentheses

#Only replacements of the type:  "2023_-_02_-_04 19:00" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = re.sub(r"(?!\()" + identificate_hours_blocking + r"\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*(?:a\s*la(?:s| )|)\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[1]}_-_{m[2]}_-_{m[3]}({m[4] or '00'}:{m[5] or '00'} {m[6] or m[7] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> print after first  re.sub()

#Only replacements of the type:  "19:00 2023_-_02_-_04" --> "(2023_-_01_-_11(19:00 pm))"
input_text = re.sub(r"(?!\()" + date_format_00_blocking + r"\s*" + identificate_hours + r"\s*(?:del|de\s*el|de |)\s*" + date_format_00 + r"\s*" + identificate_hours_blocking + r"\s*(?!\))",
                    lambda m: (f"({m[5]}_-_{m[6]}_-_{m[7]}({m[1] or '00'}:{m[2] or '00'} {m[3] or m[4] or 'am'}))"),
                    input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
print(repr(input_text)) # --> print after second re.sub()
```

Given the input received in the `input_text` variable, 2 replacements must be performed using the `re.sub()` function (or similar), but these replacements must be performed only under certain conditions. I have tried many times to restrict these possibilities so that unwanted replacements are not made prematurely within the code.

Neither of this two `re.sub()` functions should modify those date-time `Y*_MM_DD hh:ss am or pm`  that are protected by parentheses, like this `(Y*_MM_DD(hh:ss am or pm))`. For this reason I have placed this restrictions at the beginning `(?!\()` and at the end `(?!\))`

The first `re.sub()` should not replace dates if a `hour:minutes` ahead is specified.

The second `re.sub()` should not replace dates if a `hour:minutes` is specified behind.

For some unknown reason **my negative-lookahead are not working** and I get this **wrong output**:

```
#wrong output print after first  re.sub()
'en la montaña a las ((2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm))aasassa(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))fgfg'

#wrong output print after second re.sub()
'en la montaña a las ((2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))(19:00 pm)) o a las(2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm))aasassa(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))sdshdhshj 19:00 pm(2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am))fgfg'
```

And this is the **correct output** I'm trying to get

```
#correct output print after first  re.sub()
'en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) aasassa  (2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am)) sdshdhshj 19:00 pm 2023_-_02_-_04 fgfg'

#correct output print after second re.sub()
'en la montaña a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) o a las (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) aasassa  (2023_-_02_-_04(00:00 am)) sdshdhshj (2023_-_02_-_04(19:00 pm)) fgfg'
```

Comment: It seems like there is a lot going on in your code. I think that in the first part of the `re.sub` you could use a lookbehind like this `re.sub(r"(?<!\()"` and then start this part with a word boundary like `date_format_00 = r"\b(\d+)` Also, you are using  unnecessary non capture groups and alternations like  this `(?:\:| )` is the same as `[: ]` and perhaps use a single optional capture group for `(?:(am)|(pm))?` like `([ap]m)?` Can you update the question with just one example that should work? Perhaps you can deduce the second pattern. Do you want to write `'00'` if there is no group value?

Comment: @Thefourthbird If the number does not appear but the general structure does, then put a 00 in its place